# DNN 7 installation

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I'm trying to configure a DotNetNuke 7 (DNN 7) but the following error occur

```
ERROR:Index #: 0
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Class: 20
Number: 2
Message:
```

the database is SQL server 2008 R2, both database and web server on localhost. I checked the username and all instruction in the following like carefully but nothing changed
the installation guide link 
http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community/learn/video-library/view-video/video/515/view/details/dnn-7-0-installation-part-1-file-system-configuration

Comment: Looks like DNN install can't connect to your SQL Server.

Comment: so, how could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check to verify that you SQL Server instance name is the Default instance, if it isn't, you'll need to change the name when connecting to it.

Something like "localhost" would work for the default instance, but if you named it something else, you would use "localhost/somethingelse"

You also should attempt to connect to your DB server using SQL Server Management Studio, with the exact same information you are trying to use in DNN.

Comment: I connect using the following parameters - `server name = .\SQLEXPRESS`, Its accessible in **SQL Server Management Studio** without any problems

Answer (score 0):

This is an elder question, but hopefully somebody benefits from this answer.

My connection string in DNN's web.config looks like this:

```
<add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This is an SQL Server 2016 Express instance. The MDF file will be in the App_Data folder of the DNN installation.